# Android: Custom size of menu item

Tags: android, menu, options-menu

I am building an app and one of the activities has an options menu. I was wondering if it is possible to decide the size of one of the items on the menu.

I mean, the menu already has 3 options, and I want to add a fourth one, but keeping the other three together, since they all relate to the same. Something like this:

> |  ------- Op1 ------- |
>
> | Op2 | Op3 | Op4 |

Is there any way to control this? Because I think that if I just add the 4th option I am getting a 2x2 menu. I am looking for some kind of parameter I could add to the XML description of the item to make it "grow" the three columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so that it is possible because android OS itself determines this and there is no API using which you can change OR handle this thing.

Comment: I guess I could implement my own View, but I was looking for something simple. If not, I can reorganize my menu with a submenu for the 3 options. Thanks for answering so fast!!